# ApplicationVerificationFailed from Nativescript CLI

Tags: ios, nativescript

I am using the latest version (2.0) of the Nativescript CLI. I recently updated by iPad to iOS 9.3 from iOS 7. Prior to this upgrade, I was able to run Nativescript apps on my device using "tns run ios". Since the upgrade, I get the following error:

> Error: ApplicationVerificationFailed 
>   ErrorDescription: The bundle being installed with bundle ID org.nativescript.bluetoothdemo2 is authorized by a free provisioning profile, but apps validated by those are not allowed to be installed from this source.

I have attempted to change the bundle ID (hence the 2) and generate new provisioning profiles to no avail. I have opened the project in xCode and the "Fix It" button is not available. The project does run in xCode.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I solved the same problem.

1) Opened up XCode project that Nativescript generated, tried to run it, but it failed with message that apphas to be verified on the phone itself.

2) Opened up phone General settings > Profiles and Devices Management > Developer App.

3) Verified the app.

4) Built and run app via "tns run ios --device 1" normally without any problems.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: The important step here is to install with XCode once, I guess. Before that the app was not uploading to the phone.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you try the following:

1) Remove the platform/ios by running `tns platform remove ios`

2) Make sure your `package.json` contains the correct bundleID (this will be passed to your xcode project when you build).

3) Make sure you use the same BundleID from your Apple dev-certificates.

4) Add the platform/ios by running `tns platform add ios`

5) Prepare & Build: `tns prepare ios` & `tns build ios`

6) Go to your .../platforms/ios folder and open the .xcodeproj or .xcworkspace

7) Go to "General" tab of you main app target and under "Identity" group make sure you have the correct BundleID and the correct Team (your Apple dev account).

8) Go to `Build Settings` tab and under `Code Signing` group the `Code Signing Identity` key is set to `iOS Developer` (your dev Certificate), and that the `Provisioning Profile` is set to `Automatic` (when publishing it will automatically choose the correct profile).

Now you can just close XCode and run the app via CLI.

Comment: I basically went through all of these steps originally. I need to try to a clean app to see if I get the same problem. I'll report back. I feel like there is some trust issue in iOS 9 but I'm not sure.

Comment: How can I add the BundleID to Apple dev-certificates or my account?

Comment: Log inn to your apple developer account, and go to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles. Under "App IDs" section you can add app-ids, one for each app or a wildcard-certificate (usually generated by xcode). Wildcard is only for development and cannot be used to publish apps to AppStore.

Comment: Where do you log in? In their website? I don't see anything about certificates here: https://developer.apple.com/account/#/welcome